# Rendering problems with PrimeFaces + PrimeFaces Mobile + MyFaces ExtVal

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces, omnifaces

I am trying to use together the three frameworks: PrimeFaces, PrimeFaces Mobile and MyFaces ExtVal. The library versions are: PF 3.3.1, PF Mobile 0.9.3, MyFaces ExtVal 2.0.5. Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Primefaces Mobile test</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Oi" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

If the project has only PrimeFaces and Mobile jars, the rendered commandButton is as expected:

```
<button id="j_idt6:j_idt7" name="j_idt6:j_idt7" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt6:j_idt7'});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Oi</span></button>
```

This is the default PrimeFaces renderer. If i configure f:view with renderKitId as PRIMEFACES_MOBILE, the rendered button is:

```
<button id="j_idt6:j_idt7" name="j_idt6:j_idt7" type="submit" data-iconpos="left" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt6:j_idt7'});return false;">Oi</button>
```

It is also OK, as expected. Now, adding MyFaces ExtVal jars, everything breaks and only the PRIMEFACES_MOBILE is the renderer of the components. To test the behavior, i added the jars: myfaces-extval-bean-validation-2.0.5.jar, myfaces-extval-core-2.0.5.jar and myfaces-extval-property-validation-2.0.5.jar. Then i removed the renderKitId, so that the default PrimeFaces library should be used but again the result is:

```
<button id="j_idt6:j_idt7" name="j_idt6:j_idt7" type="submit" data-iconpos="left" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt6:j_idt7'});return false;">Oi</button>
```

I tried forcing the renderKitId in f:view to HTML_BASIC, but it keeps rendering the PrimeFaces Mobile version of the commandButton.

So guys, do you have any suggestions? Before the definition of RenderKitId, my system was OK, when i upgraded the libraries i got this error. I posted in [PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19910), but i couldn't see a way to solve, and i can't see why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that experience the same error that i'm having, this problem is specific to the way MyFaces EXTVAL was working with the renderkit ids. Today, with the help of @Howard i saw a new fix from the EXTVAL guys which solved the problem.

To see more information:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXTVAL-151
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=90933#p90933

I would like to thank @Howard for the support since last year, and the MyFaces EXTVAL team for the fix. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

@Fernando, I just reported a similar issue that I experienced with OmniFaces, MyFaces JAR and PrimeFaces Mobile JAR. OmniFaces fixed it, and said the following:

> Comment 4 by project member balusc, Today (4 hours ago)
> In MyFaces, the render kit ID is set during building of the view (and in Mojarra during creating of the view). Hence the temporary view didn't had the right render kit ID.
>
> This is been fixed: [view source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/f1dbe713fec889fab2af6ffedc517b4d108e1cd8)

This 'may' fix your issue as well. It's available in OmniFaces 1.3. Add the JAR to your classpath, retest, and reply with test results. I don't think it is necessary for you to make any changes to your web.xml or faces-config.xml. If I'm not mistaking, OmniFaces has a PartialViewContext called OmniPartialView(Context), but you may need to add OmniFaces's FullAjaxExceptionHandler to faces-config.xml, and that may fix this issue for you.

Comment: I tried with the omnifaces-1.3-SNAPSHOT-20121106.jar but i got the same behavior.

Actually the trouble is that there isn't an specific error. What really happens is that the mobile render kit is set default, ignoring any configuration of the desired renderkit. In my stackoverflow question i put some steps to reproduce, and i just created a simple view with a commandButton, and seeing the tomcat logs, nothing happens, just the rendered component isn't the HTML_BASIC one.

The exact problem is with the MyFaces Extval lib, if i just remove their jars everything works as desired.

Comment: It would be best to add a MyFaces jira for this but I'm sure OmniFaces could add a utility to their library which can fix this. Oh I forgot to ask you to add the enable restotable view component to your page that exhibits this behavior but you would have to follow test steps that I listed in omnifaces issue 88. It's still best to add feature request to omnifaces issue tracker to fix this issue, if MyFaces jira doesn't get fixed.